# Python os.path.getmtime Error 2

Tags: windows, python-2.7, os.path

I have written a bit of code in python 2.7 to pull a list of files from a given directory and output to a csv file. Fairly simple and for the most part it works great. I am using this code to get the file names and add them to a list. Then I will print the list once gathered. There are command line options to determine which extensions to use.  This is working fine.

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(lines):
    if searchtype == 'all':
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    elif searchtype == 'audio':
        for extensions in audio_ext:
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extensions):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    elif searchtype == 'video':
        for extensions in video_ext:
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extensions):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

The issue occurs when I attempt to get the modified date before printing using this.

```
for entries in matches:
   mod_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(entries)).\
                    strftime ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This works for some files and then errors out with error code 2.

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'E:\\Mp3s\\Artists_A-D\\Beatles, The\\Anthology 1\\60 - Kansas City  Hey-Hey-Hey-Hey!.mp3'
```

The file as printed from the list (matches) is as:

```
E:\Mp3s\Artists_A-D\Beatles, The\Anthology 1\60 - Kansas City  Hey-Hey-Hey-Hey!.mp3
```

Now the file is there for sure and if I skip doing the modified date and just print out the file names there is no issues. It rolls through 50k files without issues. so I am bit stumped. At first I thought it was the ! messing up the path but it does not seem to be the case since it prints fine without the mod date. I even updated the mod date to see if that was it, still no joy.  I am still fairly new to Python so any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried simply `os.path.getmtime(r"E:\Mp3s\Artists_A-D\Beatles, The\Anthology 1\60 - Kansas City  Hey-Hey-Hey-Hey!.mp3")` ? we don't need all the code above. The shorter the [mcve] the better.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - actually, I think showing the code with `os.walk` is useful - it shows that the file name was created from an `os.path.join` of valid names, so this isn't a typing error.

Comment: The difference with `getmtime` is that it has to hand the path to the file system to get information. I'm grasping at straws here, but maybe there is some non-ascii character in there (a fancy space or dash). You could copy the mp3 to `foo.mp3` and it will likely work. The bigger question... why python 2? This may start automagically working with python 3.x which has better unicode support.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am using python 2.7 because that is what is used at my job. I am expected to learn it, so I am learning the version that they use.  I did rename it and it went past that and failed at another. so it is the - symbol that is off. I renamed the file to the exact same thing and it worked.  So I copied the filename of the next failed, that has a dash in it, and pasted it into notepad+ and I get a box symbol. So that character is not really a dash.  Perhaps it is a dash in disguise.  So how do I handle that code wise?